# Which one has better Performance?

Tags: identity-based-encryption

Sending secret value in identity-based encryption
Using xor : $K \oplus e(g,h)^{\gamma}$
Using symmetric key: Assuming $Key=e(g,h)^{\gamma}$ and encrypt $K$ using $Key$.

Which one is better in performance?

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you mean "performance" as in "speed", or are you hinting at something else (like "security")?

Comment: Good question, I assumed speed in the answer below.

Comment: e-sushi. speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that you can use a one-time-pad they would be equivalent. Otherwise a cipher will always be slower than XOR.

The chances that it matters much compared to the other functions required is about zero though.

Comment: Note: I'm not an expert in identity based encryption (yet), but this question seems to be answerable without expert knowledge. I'm not sure if an IV is required for above function though.